# Position ButtonBox in Window

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

I've created a window in GTK3 and I'm trying to add 2 buttons to the bottom of the window.

To do so, I created a `ButtonBox` and packed the 2 buttons. But I wanted the buttons to appear at the bottom of the screen and I have no idea how to achieve this. Right now they appear in the middle of the screen.

I've tried this:

```
button_Box.set_layout(Gtk::ButtonBoxStyle::BUTTONBOX_CENTER);
```

but that didn't seem to do anything.

I've also tried

```
button_Box.set(Gtk::Align::ALIGN_END);
```

but this throws an error

> "error: ‘class Gtk::ButtonBox’ has no member named ‘set’
>     button_Box.set(Gtk::Align::ALIGN_END);"

where `button_Box` is the name of my `ButtonBox` object.

Comment: I added a vertical box and packed the buttonBox at the end. This seems to place it at the bottom of the screen. Would be wonderful to know if there is a better method to do so.

Comment: Gtk follows the model of boxes inside boxes, so adding the vertical box is correct but unless you add more widgets to the container you won't see any differences. Try adding a simple widget (eg. GtkLabel or GtkImage) to the box (above the buttonbox) and set it (the new widget) to expand vertically. Then your button box will be at the bottom.